# Universal Windows App Debug on Device Not Working

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to deploy and debug a UWP app onto a physical device.  The Device is an Acer Iconia W1-810 Tab 8 running Windows 10 Home.  The development environment is also Windows 10 running VS2015 Community.  The Acer is set to Developer mode and the screen is unlocked.

According to my reading of [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps) I should be able to connect the device via USB and deploy and debug directly on the device.  At first I couldn't get the PC to see the device as `Windows Phone IP over USB Transport (IpOverUsbSvc)` was disabled.  Enabling that means I can now see the table on the network under the `Phones` category.

The project in VS is also set to `Uninstall and then re-install my package ...`

Selecting `Device` as the debug target in VS yields this error:

> DEP6200 : Bootstrapping failed. Device cannot be found. 0x89731810:
>   Deployment failed because no Windows Phone was detected. Make sure a
>   phone is connected and powered on.

Selecting `Remote Machine` as the target device yeilds:

> Error: Unable to connect to the Microsoft Visual Studio Remote
>   Debugger named '192.168.0.7'.  The Visual Studio 2015 Remote Debugger
>   (MSVSMON.EXE) does not appear to be running on the remote computer.
>   This may be because a firewall is preventing communication to the
>   remote computer. Please see Help for assistance on configuring remote
>   debugging.

Which is understandable as I don't have this installed at the moment.  But from my understanding the first scenario should be working and I'd rather not install a debugger on device unless absolutely required.

What do I need to configure in order to get the first debug scenario working?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might not have installed the visual studio remote tools on your target machine.  You need to do that first before you can do any remote debugging.

Here are the instructions:

1. Download the Visual Studio Remote Tools from one of the links provided at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx
2. Install the remote tools on the target machine
3. Start the remote debugger on the target machine
4. From visual studio click on small lack the arrow to the right of the debug button, and make sure "Remote Machine" is selected
5. When prompted, enter the IP of the device that you want to debug at.

(It sounds like you already know steps 4 and 5, but I included them for completeness)